# Цикл for не выводит последний элемент

Tags: python, selenium, for

Сначала я перебираю ссылки, а потом по этим ссылкам идет селениум, но он не показывает последний 30-ый элемент страницы, хотя `len(urls)` 30
Что, как, почему?

```
for el in elems:
    a = el.get_attribute("href")
    url ={
        "href":a
        }
    urls.append(url)
print(len(urls))
for j in urls:
    browser.get(j["href"])
    for element in browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('span.green-text'):
        print(element.text)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Первый элемент - нулевой, второй - 1...

Comment: @vikttur у меня на странице 30 ссылок. Первый for показывает len(urls)=30
Делаю принт, а там 29 элементов

Comment: возможно `for element in browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('span.green-text')` иногда возвращает пустой массив

Comment: @Danis нет, тут что-то с очередью..
Сейчас код работает так: сначала переход на следующую страницу, а потом происходит показ элемента

Comment: Понатыкайте отладочный print после каждой строки да проверьте, делов то

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, программа не успевала спарсить и переходила дальше.
Добавил

```
While x!=0:
   try: 
     код
     x=0
   except:
     continue
   break
```

и все начало работать